# Connect from Access 2010 to SQL Server 2000 and then import a CSV file into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2000, ms-access-2010

I was given a new computer at work with a new O/S and the latest version of Microsoft Access.
I used to have Access 2003.  Now I have Access 2010.

I used to be able to have an Access 2003 Project linked to a SQL Server 2000 database, and when I opened the Access 2003 project to import a comma-delimited text file, a file (EDIT: more precisely, a table) would be created in SQL Server and the data from the text file would end up in SQL Server.

Now I want to do the same thing now, but Access 2010 is different and I cannot see how it's done.

Menu choices:

**Database Tools -> SQL Server** executes an upsizing tool which is not compatible with SQL Server 2000.

**External Data -> ODBC Database** does allow me to attach to the existing SQL Server 2000 database, but when I import a CSV file, the table is created locally in Access, not in SQL Server 2000.

Can Access 2010 be used to import data in to SQL Server 2000? How?

Thanks

Comment: Were you using an Access Data Project before in Access 2003? Did importing a text file create a new table in SQL Server 2000? You say a "file" would be created in SQL Server. I'm really not sure what you mean.

Comment: @HK1: Yes, previously had ADP in 2003 pointing at SQL Server 2000. Importing a CSV into the ADP resulted in a table being created automagically in SQL Server, populated with the data from the CSV.

Comment: I don't think this is possible outside of an ADP.

Comment: @HK1: and it's not possible to create an ADP with Access 2010?

Comment: I'm actually not sure how you do it but I'm pretty sure you can still make an ADP in Access 2010. The way I understand, there's less reason to do it now than there used to be and a lot of guys (like myself) are just connecting to SQL Server from Access mdb/accdb using ODBC linked tables. I personally don't use any automated tools for creating tables in SQL Server and I don't need that capability either. I don't make new tables that often.

Comment: You might check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500519/pros-and-cons-of-access-data-project-ms-access-front-end-with-sql-server-backen

Comment: @HK1: Actually, I can create an ADP, just by providing the .ADP extension on the filename. There's no save-as option for ADP any longer. The import problem still exists. Imported data sent to a new table results in the table being created client-side, not on the server.

Comment: @HK1: thanks for that link, but that's a debate on the pros and cons of using ADPs in general, and I know the benefits, and one of the main benefits for us seems to have been removed in 2010 -- i.e. supremely easy import of CSV directly into a new table in SQL Server via Access wizard in the front-end. Maybe it only affects SQL Server 2000, but we have some legacy apps that still must be supported.

Comment: ADP is incredibly fast for importing CSV files if you use BULK INSERT command via TSQL.

Comment: @AaronKempf: Datatype craziness has been my experience with bulk insert and CSV. With Access as the intermediary, things went smoother. Are you suggesting that Access can still be the intermediary in some way when issuing BULK INSERT command?

Comment: Yes.. I can issue TSQL commands directly against the SQL engine when I use ADP. Or, can do this via SQLPT

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx

Using pipes to import data from a file


The following example imports order detail information into the AdventureWorks.Sales.SalesOrderDetail table from the specified data file by using a pipe (|) as the field terminator and |\n as the row terminator.






Copy


BULK INSERT AdventureWorks.Sales.SalesOrderDetail
   FROM 'f:\orders\lineitem.tbl'
   WITH 
      (
         FIELDTERMINATOR =' |',
         ROWTERMINATOR =' |\n'
      )

Comment: The old way would create the file for you on the server.  I'm importing tables with dozens of columns on a frequent basis, and having to design the target table each time (the structure varies) is a real time-eater.

Comment: yes, I agree.. right-click import of text files is immensely useful, as is importing ranges from Excel into SQL Server.. I just don't know WTH I'm going to do with the death of ADP. Breaks my heart. I love love love ADP. I use EXTERNAL DATA/TEXT FILE all day every day using ADP against SQL 2008, doesn't this work with SQL 2000???  I tried setting up a SQL 2000 machine the other day, and I gave up, I just can't deal with old operating systems.  On the other hand, I use SQL 2000 SSAS all day every day :)

Answer (score -1):

you can issue a BULK INSERT stored procedure from SQL Server directly, this should be a dozen times faster than anything that MS access can do natively.

Comment: why the downvote?? bulk insert TSQL command is faster than anything that MS Access can do natively.